# Extracting a string from a file in Python and include the related value

Tags: python, regex, string, bash

Does anyone know how I could extract the known string "name:" from a text file and also extract the related value which could be up to 12 characters long?

For example the string is within the file "test" and contains:

```
h2. abc value\r\n * Name: name123\r\n\r\ details more words
```

How would I extract just the values `Name: name123` if the key `Name:` is always the same but the value `name123` changes all the time?

```
import re
import sys
import string

with open('file') as theFile
  r = theFile.read()
print(r)

theName = re.compile(r'Name:')
mod1 = theName.search(r)
print(mod1)
```

Output:

```
<re.Match object; span(23, 33) match='Name:'>
```

How would I only return the result "Name: " + "name123"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a capture group to capture everything after `Name:`.

```
theName = re.compile(r'Name:\s*(.*)')
mod1 = theName.search(r)
if mod1:
    print(mod1.group(1))
```

`\s*` will skip over the whitespace after `Name:`, and `.*` will match the rest of the line. The parentheses capture that match.

Comment: Thanks Barmar! But what if I want the search to capture only up to the word "details" instead of the whole line?

Comment: The line ends at `\r\n`

Comment: Great, this is what I am looking for. Thank you!